# Can I use the ® symbol in the play store for a trademark registered in the Benelux?

Tags: trademark

When publishing an app in the Google Play store, I would like to use the ® symbol for the name of a product that is not registered as a trademark in the USA, but it has been registered as such in the Benelux. Is it fine to use the ® symbol there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears that you can. In [§ 906.01](https://tmep.uspto.gov/RDMS/TMEP/Apr2016#/Apr2016/TMEP-900d1e1285.html) of the Trademark Manual of Examining Procedure (TMEP) it states:

> In addition to the United States, several countries recognize use of the symbol ® to designate registration.  When a foreign applicant’s use of the symbol on the specimens is based on a registration in a foreign country, the use is appropriate.

Crucially, the country it is registered in must provide for the use of the ® symbol in its law. A discussion of this can be found in the Trademark Trial and Appeal Board case *Brown Shoe Co. v. Robbins* ([PDF](https://e-foia.uspto.gov/Foia/RetrievePdf?system=TTABIS&flNm=91176273-05-13-2009), pg. 14-15).

Since the TMEP lists the Benelux countries as providing for the use of the ® symbol, your use would be appropriate.

Comment: What does the TMEP have to do with the Google play store?

Comment: @phoog Submissions to the Google Play store have to comply with U.S. law (which I believe the OP knew by asking this question). The TMEP is USPTO's manual on examining trademarks and trademark disputes and as such is a source for adjudicating trademark disputes in the Google Play store. For more information, see the [TMEP's introduction](https://tmep.uspto.gov/RDMS/TMEP/Apr2016#/Apr2016/introductiond1e1.html)